# Extract image frames from live non-youtube video streams

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, computer-vision, video-streaming

I am trying to extract https videos which are live streaming on earthcam.net, skyline.net, etc. I have been,

```
FFmpeg -i "https://<>" -vf fps=1/5 out%d.png
```

but it gives `Invalid data found when processing input`

Comment: My guess is that the input contains invalid data. What exact URL are you trying? You’re not trying the url for the HTML page are you?

Comment: @szatmary I am using mostly earthcam video links for example; `https://www.earthcam.com/usa/florida/miamiandthebeaches/?cam=miamibeach10`

Comment: That URL points to an HTML file, not a video file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is by using streamlink in python. That will give you the m3u8 file which can be read by opencv `cam = VideoCapture(streamlink_output)`